# onclose/onunload in a new window (window.open) for external url

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, popup

Is there any way to capture the event onclose of the window? I am trying to auth the user on twitter with a popup. And I would like to reject the request/promise if the user close the window.

The problem is onclose does not exists and onunload works on urls of the same domain. I have tried an iframe, but twitter do not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

No., There is no event for capturing window close event.

Try using  `window.unload(function(){})` in the current page.

above event triggered while refreshing the page or navigating from the current page.